I can't get then action button in a modular shiny app to work even in a pared back example
Could not get the action button to submit the data I need it to. Pared it back and I can't even get the action button to print a success message. New to modular shiny, so not sure if there is a problem there
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# Numeric Input Module ----
measurement_input_module_ui <- function(id, label = "Label") {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    numericInput(
      inputId = ns("numeric_input1"),
      label = label,
      value = 0,
      min = 5,
      max = 60
    )
  )
}

measurement_input_module_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      reactive({ input$numeric_input1 })
    }
  )
}

# Student Tab Module ----
student_tabBox_module_UI <- function(id, student_number) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tabBox(
    title = paste("Subject", student_number),
    id = ns("student_box"),
    width = 12,
    tabPanel(
      title = "Unstressed Condition",
      measurement_input_module_ui(ns("unstressed_input"), label = "Input"),
      actionButton(ns("submit_button"), "Submit"),
      textOutput(ns("success_message"))
    )
  )
}

student_tabBox_module_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns
      unstressed_value <- measurement_input_module_server("unstressed_input")
      
      observeEvent(input$submit_button, {
        output$success_message <- renderText({
          paste("Success")
        })
      })
    }
  )
}

# Measurements Module ----
measurements_module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidRow(
    uiOutput(ns("students_ui"))
  )
}

measurements_module_server <- function(id, student_data) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns
      
      observe({
        req(student_data())
        num_students <- nrow(student_data())
        
        if (num_students > 0) {
          output$students_ui <- renderUI({
            lapply(1:num_students, function(i) {
              student_tabBox_module_UI(
                id = paste0("student_module_", i),
                student_number = student_data()$Initials[i]
              )
            })
          })
          
          lapply(1:num_students, function(i) {
            student_tabBox_module_server(
              id = paste0("student_module_", i)
            )
          })
        } else {
          output$students_ui <- renderUI({
            h3("No students available. Please add students to proceed.")
          })
        }
      })
    }
  )
}

# Main App UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  measurements_module_ui("measurements_module")
)

# Main App Server ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {

    student_data <- reactive({
    data.frame(
      ID = 1:2,
      Initials = c("A.B.", "C.D."),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  })
  
  measurements_module_server("measurements_module", student_data)
}

# Run App ----
shinyApp(ui, server)


Obviously this module is being called in the main app. I can see everything from the ui and other parts of the app work, it's just the action button that won't work.
Edit: more expansive MWE as requested. I'm now wondering if the problem is somewhere in the nested modules?

You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. This post may help.

Works fine for me.

Please add a working minimal shiny app that integrates the module.  Add library calls too.  Where does tabBox() come from?

hi i expanded the example - i'm still really stuck
